# This site can’t be reached The webpage at http://0.0.0.0/ might be temporarily down?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

It  seems my setting is up and ok:

[image]

But when I try localhost:8300 or 8310, I get an error:

```
This site can’t be reachedThe webpage at http://0.0.0.0/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID
```

Comment: It sounds like you have a bogus entry in "/etc/hosts" or something.  The IP 0.0.0.0 is not a real IP address.  It is a "wild card".  It means "all addresses".  You can't connect to it and therefore you shouldn't configure "localhost" to resolve to it.

Comment: Try url with IP:Port format.

Comment: @user432797 : Please post this type of questions on [sf] instead of [so].

Comment: I don't see that you have forwarded the ports `8300` and `8310`.
have you tried ssh-ing into the image using `docker exec -it production_openemr_1 /bin/bash` and health check if server is listining on those ports `telnet localhost 8300`

Comment: @saleemKhair how to forward it?

Comment: @learner34 I already tried both, it did not work!

Comment: can you share your docker-compose.yml?

Comment: @stephenC I just followed the instructions of installation!

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: @saleemkhair it is the same file from github, I got it from openemr github page, I used the docker-compose.yml in “docker/production/“ path

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that you are forwarding those ports.
first try to ssh into the docker image using `docker exec -it production_openemr_1 /bin/bash`
This will log you inside the image, then try heath checking the server using `telnet 0.0.0.0 8300` and `telnet 0.0.0.0 8310` if the connection was successful this means that you need to forward those 2 ports from the image to your host.

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    ports:
      - "8300:8300" 
      - "8310:8310"
.
.
```

left side is the host port and right side is the image ports, so you can have different port for the host thats forwarded to `8300` in the image for example `-"8001:8300"` will give you ability to access the containers address`http:/0.0.0.0:8300` by using `http://0.0.0.0:8001` from host.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will try it tomorrow and update you!

Comment: Its worth mentioning that prot `443` - https (TLS/SSL) - and port `80` - http - are already forwarded, and those ports require special premissions on the host to open.. so If you consider using them make sure that the user running that runs docker daemon have those permissions, usually its a service user named `docker` with group `docker` aswell